# Application of Ordinary Generation Functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am attempting to solve this combinatorics question whilst applying what has been learnt in ordinary generating functions.

[image: Question]

and this is my attempt so far...

[image: Attempt so far]

1) Am I correct so far?
2) If yes, how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What allows you to say that $1/(X-1)^4=\sum \binom{r+4-1}{r} X^{r}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It's a proven result from my lecture notes that 1/(1-X)^n = Summ[(n+r-1)Cr * x^r]

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten the existence of the generalized formula for $(1+X)^{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-k}{n}$